# Converter milissegundos para formato hh:mm em java

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um game Android com uma engine em java onde tem um Timer que fica o tempo todo rodando durante o Game... Este timer é um contador de milissegundos e é acrescentado em um long.

No final preciso converter este long para um formato em horas e minutos (hh:mm), como faço isto em java?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 1) Resposta rápida:

```
String.format( "%03d:%02d", ms / 3600000, ( ms / 60000 ) % 60 );
```

## 2) Solução "tradicional" matemática:

### Calculando os campos:

Supondo que `ms` seja a variável dos milisegundos:

```
   segundos = ( ms / 1000 ) % 60;      // se não precisar de segundos, basta remover esta linha.
   minutos  = ( ms / 60000 ) % 60;     // 60000   = 60 * 1000
   horas    = ms / 3600000;            // 3600000 = 60 * 60 * 1000
   System.out.println( String.format( "%03d:%02d", horas, minutos ) );
```

- O operador `%` é chamado de módulo (na verdade é "resto de divisão", não são sinônimos): `A % B` devolve o resto da divisão de `A` por `B`;
- O `%` foi utilizado nos `segundos` e `minutos` para que ficassem restritos de 0 a 59;
- Em `horas`, não foi aplicado `%` para permitir saídas como `107:38`, por exemplo.

Caso queira, pode acrescentar uma nova linha para calcular os dias, usando a mesma lógica:

```
   segundos = ( ms / 1000 ) % 60;  
   minutos  = ( ms / 60000 ) % 60;     // 60000    = 60 * 1000
   horas    = ( ms / 3600000 ) % 24;   // 3600000  = 60 * 60 * 1000
   dias     = ms / 86400000            // 86400000 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

### Formatando a saída:

Para a saída, usamos o `String.format()` com a máscara `"%03d:%02d"`, que nos retorna 3 casas preenchidas por zero à esquerda no primeiro parâmetro, e duas para o segundo:

```
   107:38
```

Se quiser acrescentar os segundos ao contador, basta atualizar o `String.format`:

```
   segundos = ( ms / 1000 ) % 60;
   minutos  = ( ms / 60000 ) % 60;     // 60000   = 60 * 1000
   horas    = ms / 3600000;            // 3600000 = 60 * 60 * 1000
   System.out.println( String.format( "%03d:%02d:%02d", horas, minutos,segundos ) );
```

Saída:

```
   107:38:13
```

## 3) Solução utilizando java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

Caso a classe `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` esteja disponível (Android API 9+), pode ser usado este código (supondo que `ms` seja a variável dos milissegundos):

```
   String.format("%03d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours( ms ),
                              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( ms ) % 60 );
```

Mencionei só pra comentar que a classe existe. Me parece um exagero essa alternativa.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta! Mas, porque te parece um exagero o uso do TimeUnit, e porque esta usando % 60? Achei que no caso do TimeUnit ele já convertia

Comment: @felipe.rce Primeiro pela desnecessidade de fazer o fluxo do programa ir pra uma outra classe que no fim vai justamente fazer os cálculos de qualquer forma, mais o overhead das chamadas. Fazendo o cálculo você mesmo, como é simples, chega no mesmo resultado com muito menos operações da máquina. Quanto ao %60, vale lembrar que 37200000ms virariam 62 minutos, pois as horas não estão sendo descontadas, e o que queremos é 001:02 e não 001:62.

Answer (score 7):

Diferente das soluções usando cálculos matemáticos, proponho uma que, embora seja simples, permite ser facilmente adaptada para outros formatos.

O método a seguir recebe o tempo em milissegundos e usa a classe `Calendar` para calcular os milissegundos e a formatação de datas padrão do Java para retornar o formato desejado:

```java
public static String msToHourSecond( int ms ) {
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.set( Calendar.HOUR , 0 );
  c.set( Calendar.MINUTE , 0 );
  c.set( Calendar.SECOND , 0 );
  c.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND , 0 );
  c.add( Calendar.MILLISECOND , ms );
  return new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm" ).format( c.getTime() );
}
```

Exemplos de uso:

```java
System.out.println( msToHourSecond( 1000 * 60 * 11 ) ); // 11 minutos
System.out.println( msToHourSecond( 1000 * 60 * ( 15 + 60 * 2 ) ) ); // 2 horas e 15 minutos
```

Saída:

> 00:11
>   02:15