# Tipo de objeto para dados do tipo Tempo (Ex: 1 min e 56 segundos) em Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, time, tipagem

Estou necessitando trabalhar com tempos, como por exemplo um cronometro (não é meu caso), que ao fim de sua execução teria que guarda o seu valor.

Então pensei em algumas possibilidades como:

- `java.utils.Date`: só que os dados no caso não são uma Data;
- Em `long`: guardando os tempos em milissegundos, e o converter para os formatos necessários sempre que necessário; (se for por essa caminho encontrei esses dois exemplo de conversões: [esse aqui mesmo no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14260/converter-milissegundos-para-formato-hhmm-em-java), e [esse](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/))
- Criar meu próprio objeto `Tempo`, que faça o controle sobre milissegundos como na opção anterior;

Minha duvida é a seguinte (Segue meu algoritmo da pergunta):

```java
String pergunta = "Há alguma forma/tipo no Java que seja adequada a esse tipo de informação"
                + ", que não seja uma forma adaptativa como no caso de armazenar em um long?";
boolean resposta = fazerPerguntaComRespotaBoolean(pergunta);
String perguntaSecundaria = null;
if(resposta == true){
    perguntaSecundaria = "Qual seria? E como utilizar?";
} else {
    perguntaSecundaria = "Qual forma adaptativa é mais 'adaptativa' e esse tipo de dados?";
}

String respotaSecundaria = fazerPerguntaComRespotaDissertativa(perguntaSecundaria);
System.out.println(respotaSecundaria);
```

> Obs: Se alguém se incomodar, ou se ficou complicado de entender minha pergunta, removo o formato de algoritmo de minha pergunta, sem problemas, é só para descontrair.

Comment: Algum problema com o https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html? Conjece o http://www.joda.org/joda-time/? Leu isto https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html?

Comment: @bigown, não conhecia não, já dei uma olhada superficial e parece que vai ajudar, vou ver como trabalhar com tempos com esses objetos como citado na pergunta, ex: `14h 23m 34s`. Valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recentemente estive utilizando o [date4j](http://www.date4j.net/) em um projeto android.

Também olhei o Joda Time, mas ela parece ser muito robusta em termos de tamanho e complexidade para usar em um aplicativo Android. Mas isso pode ser relativo, porque as vezes o aplicativo é tão grande que essa diferença pode ser insignificante.

Também estive pesquisando e ela tem uns problemas de performance na inicialização: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059663/android-java-joda-date-is-slow e https://github.com/christerdk/Malmofestivalen-for-Android/issues/6. Esses links podem não estar mais representando a realidade, mas foi um ponto que me influênciou na decisão no momento.

A Date4j é bem mais leve, apesar de não ser tão **completa** (isso depende da sua necessidade, a minha foi atendida), quanto a `Joda Time`. Gostei de usar a biblioteca, e parece que ela tem várias vantagens em relação a performance.

Acho que não vale a pena colocar exemplos de uso aqui, se precisar eu posso colocar com mais tempo. No [site oficial](http://www.date4j.net/) tem uma boa documentação, com exemplos até.

Assim como o Joda Time, ela também tem um repositório clone (o autor principal a princípio não gosta de maven) no Maven Central e jCenter, basta adicionar ao seu `build.gradle` a dependência:

```
compile 'com.darwinsys:hirondelle-date4j:1.5.1'
```

Comment: Legal @Wakim, estou analisando possibilidades, e parece ser uma boa opção, e também em relação ao JodaTime no próprio site da [date4j](http://www.date4j.net) eles [falam sobre os problemas do JodaTime, e seu desempenho no Android](http://www.date4j.net/#Joda).

Answer (score 2):

A biblioteca mais completa para lidar com este tipo de informação é a [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Ele é universalmente aceita pelos programadores Java como a solução quando há necessidades mais complexas de manipulação de data e hora. Mesmo quando não há necessidade de tanta complexidade ela é interessante porque resolve alguns problemas e deficiências da API oficial.

Claro que ela é pesada para alguns padrões. Existem outras bibliotecas mais leves, porém menos conhecidas e quem sabe se tão confiáveis e com futuro garantido. Se precisar de algo leve mas que atende o que você precisa e for utilizar em maior escala, não descarte fazer sua própria biblioteca talvez baseada em alguma já existente. Mas precisa pesar bem o custo (incluindo as dificuldades de fazer certo) X benefício.

Esqueça de usar o `long` puro.

Comment: Não cheguei a olhar o _revamp_ da API oficial de _date/time_ do Java 8 que parece ter sido baseada na JodaTime, você considera que em aplicações Java 8 a JodaTime é preferível em relação à API?

Comment: @Piovezan também não vi e por isto fica difícil falar, só posso confirmar o que você falou. Para quem já usa a versão 8 pode ser que a nova API oficial seja suficiente.